C++ Websocket sends corrupt or truncated Images
ive implemented a websocket in my c++ program which captures video and sends it to the client. Unfortunatly the client gets corrupt or truncated Images. I have also created a http server in the same program which publishes the same videofeed but over a REST api and there the image is not corrupted so i think the error lies in my websocket code. But i cant figure it out.
You can find the screenshots from the websocket image and REST API image here Link
#include "header/WebSocketStreamer.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>

void LatestFrameQueue::push(std::vector<uchar> value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    latest_frame_ = std::move(value);
    cond_.notify_all();
}

bool LatestFrameQueue::pop(std::vector<uchar>& value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cond_.wait(lock, [this] { return latest_frame_.has_value() || done_; });
    if (!latest_frame_.has_value()) return false;
    value = std::move(latest_frame_.value());
    latest_frame_.reset();
    return true;
}

void LatestFrameQueue::setDone() {
    done_ = true;
    cond_.notify_all();
}

session::session(tcp::socket socket, LatestFrameQueue& queue)
    : ws_(std::move(socket)), frame_queue_(queue) {}

void session::start() {
    ws_.async_accept(beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
}

void session::on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec) return fail(ec, "accept");
    do_read();
}

void session::do_read() {
    ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void session::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    if (ec == websocket::error::closed) return;
    if (ec) return fail(ec, "read");

    auto msg = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data());
    std::cout << "Received: " << msg << std::endl;

    if (msg == "start_stream") {
        should_stream_ = true;
        send_frame();
    } else if (msg == "stop_stream") {
        should_stream_ = false;
    }

    buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
    do_read();
}

void session::send_frame() {
    if (!should_stream_) return;

    std::vector<uchar> frame;
    if (frame_queue_.pop(frame)) {
        ws_.binary(true);
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(frame),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    } else {
        // If no frame available, try again shortly
        net::post(ws_.get_executor(), [self = shared_from_this()] { self->send_frame(); });
    }
}

void session::on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    if (ec) return fail(ec, "write");
    if (should_stream_) send_frame();
}

void session::fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

listener::listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint, LatestFrameQueue& queue)
    : ioc_(ioc), acceptor_(ioc), frame_queue_(queue) {
    beast::error_code ec;

    acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec) { fail(ec, "open"); return; }

    acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec) { fail(ec, "set_option"); return; }

    acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec) { fail(ec, "bind"); return; }

    acceptor_.listen(net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec) { fail(ec, "listen"); return; }
}

void listener::run() {
    do_accept();
}

void listener::do_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        net::make_strand(ioc_),
        beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
}

void listener::on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
    if (ec) {
        fail(ec, "accept");
    } else {
        std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), frame_queue_)->start();
    }
    do_accept();
}

void listener::fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

WebSocketServer::WebSocketServer(const std::string& address, unsigned short port, LatestFrameQueue& frame_queue)
    : address_(address), port_(port), frame_queue_(frame_queue), ioc_(1) {}

void WebSocketServer::start() {
    if (!is_running_) {
        is_running_ = true;
        server_thread_ = std::thread([this] { run(); });
    }
}

void WebSocketServer::stop() {
    if (is_running_) {
        is_running_ = false;
        ioc_.stop();
        if (server_thread_.joinable()) {
            server_thread_.join();
        }
    }
}

void WebSocketServer::run() {
    try {
        auto const address = net::ip::make_address(address_);
        auto const port = port_;

        std::make_shared<listener>(ioc_, tcp::endpoint{address, port}, frame_queue_)->run();

        ioc_.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "WebSocket server error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

// Update the start_websocket_server function
std::unique_ptr<WebSocketServer> start_websocket_server(const std::string& address, unsigned short port, LatestFrameQueue& frame_queue) {
    auto server = std::make_unique<WebSocketServer>(address, port, frame_queue);
    server->start();
    return server;
}

Header File

I mean, try sending a file consisting of the 32 bit values 1 through N.  And see what you receive.  This will make it clear what is being lost in the stream?  (ie, are you losing order, packets at random, or is it shutting down too early)  You could also do this in an image (send a uniform gradient of some kind), but you think the problem is in the transport layer and the image processing code on the client might get in the way.
